# Prove that $(L^*M^*)^* = (L\cup M)^*$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I would like to find out how to prove this statement. Thank you.
Well I think that I proved one part of the statement, but my proof doesn't really look elegant. 
My proof of $(L\cup M)^* \subset (L^*M^*)^*\!$.

We know that $\epsilon, L \in L^*$ and $\epsilon, M \in M^*\!$. Hence $L \subset L^*M^*$ and $M \subset L^*M^*\!$, so we can write this as $L^*M^* = (L \cup M) \cup X $. From this it follows that $(L\cup M)^*\subset (L^*M^*)^*\!$.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We want to help you with your specific problems, not just do your (home-)work. However, as it is we don't know what this problem is and thus how to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Well, there isn't much I could add to the question since I am stuck at the very beginning. I simply can't think of a way to show that this property is true. But I expect this proof to go on like this: if w is a word in first language then something implies that it's in the second language. The second part of the proof would be a converse of that statement.

Comment: @FrankW [New users can't use chat](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Comment: Can you please edit the question to clarify exactly what your question is.  I can't see anywhere in the question that actually asks a question -- it is just a list of statements, which forces us to guess at what your specific question is.  (For your information, "Please check my proof" questions are not a good fit for this site, if that's what you meant to ask; see http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/722/755.  Similarly, yes-or-no questions like "is there a more elegant proof?" don't leave us with much to work with, particularly if the answer is "no".)

Comment: The body of your question is unclear, since, as D.W. said above, there's no obvious question being asked. If one goes by your header, a charitable interpretation is "I want to prove that $(L^*M^*)^* = (L\cup M)^*$. Here's my proof of inclusion in one direction, (which I don't feel is entirely satisfactory), but I need a hint on showing $(L^*M^*)^* \subseteq (L\cup M)^*$. Can anyone point me in the right direction?" Is that what you're asking? If so, you might consider rewording the question to reflect that.

Comment: Hint: "Let $w \in (L^* M^*)^*$, i.e. $w = l_1 m_1 \dots l_k m_k$ with $l_i \in L^*$ and $m_i \in M^*$." Continue from there to show the missing inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof seems elegant to me.  It fits in about three sentences, which is probably about as good as you're going to get, for something like this.  I don't think you're going to find anything cleaner.  Or, at least, it's hard to suggest what you would find cleaner, without knowing your tastes and what you find inelegant about this proof.

One possible improvement (albeit a very slight one) would be to change the second half of your second sentence to "so we find that $L \cup M \subset L^* M^*$".

Comment: I agree but this seems to be a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I sympathize, but if this isn't an answer, I'm not sure what would qualify as an answer.  The question seems to be asking a yes-or-no question: "can you find a more elegant proof?"  My answer answers that question by saying "no".  I'm not sure what more one can say.  I think the root problem is that it's just not a very good question; basic yes-or-no questions tend not to be very good questions, and this goes double for check-my-proof questions.  The OP hasn't given us a whole lot to work with.

Comment: Not trying to be awkward but I agree with all of that, too.